# JS: If you call the function, the result is 3, but if you bind the context with f.call(f) - the result is 5

Tags: javascript, iife, executioncontext

```
var f = function() {
  this.x = 5;
  (function() {
    this.x = 3;
  })();
  console.log(this.x);
};

var obj = {
  x: 4,
  m: function() {
    console.log(this.x);
  }
};

f(); // 3
new f(); // 5
f.call(f); // 5
obj.m.call(f); // 5
```

If you call the function, the result is 3, but if you bind the context with f.call(f) - the result is 5. Also, if I call the functions as a constructor. Why it happens? Sorry for the stupid question, but I tried to find the answer, but could not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- In the first case, you call `f()` as a simple named function. So the `this` keyword inside of it refers to the global scope (the window).

  Consequence: the `this` inside the function body and the `this` inside the closure inside the function body point to the same object: the window.
- In the second case you call f() as a constructor, so the `this` keyword will point to the created object. But the closure, as it's anonymous, will keep refering to the global scope with `this`, so in this case they don't point to the same thing and the object created by the constructor `f()` is not mutated by the closure.
- In the 3rd case, you call `f` like the first time but specifying the value of `this` as being the function `f` itself. So the behavior of `this` here is equivalent to the second case.
- In the 4th case, you call `m` using the context of `f`, so the `this.x` will refer to `f` for `this`, and the closure inside `f` keeps refering to the window.